# How do you do a string replace with javascript using HTML in a script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, str-replace

I am working on a plugin for WordPress and I need to add multiple settings to be able to add multiple videos. Everything is working except for when I copy the content in the script tag, I am not able to replace a placeholder with the value I want.

Here is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/Jb6NK/1/

```
(function ($) {
    var i = 0;
    $("#add-olympvm").click(function () {
        var section = $("#blank_data").text();
        section.replace(/COUNT_KEY/g, i);
        $("#olympvm_cage tbody").append(section);
        i++;
    });
}(jQuery));
```

What I am trying to do is replace `COUNT_KEY` with the value of `i`.

I know this is possible but for the life of me I cannot seem to get this working.

Any help/pointers is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Jeremy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`String.prototype.replace` is non-destructive. It doesn't change the original string, but creates a new one. You want this:

```
section = section.replace(/COUNT_KEY/g, i);
```

Comment: Wow... can't believe I missed that. Thank you! I'll accept this as the answer when it allows me to.

Comment: Btw, JS strings are immutable, so all string methods are non-destructive.